# Is there a case I should say "in absence of" instead of "in the absence of"?

Tags: idioms, articles, definite-articles

I am checking the usage of "in the absence of".
I learned "in the absence of", but there may be some cases this phrase is written without "the".
(Example: https://ludwig.guru/s/in+absence+of+reply)

When should I write "in absence of" instead of "in the absence of"?

Is the usage of "in the absence of" correct in this sample sentence below?
The author's conclusion that most entrepreneurs are interested in fin-tech, in the absence of further evidence, is severely flawed.

Comment: I would probably use "the" in that context.  There are other contexts where I would omit it, however.

Comment: Are there any rules about when I should use "the"? Or is it safer that I always use "the"?

Comment: For certain phrases, 'the' occurs by practice.  In case of/ in the case of; for the purpose of (rather than 'for purpose of'), in the absence of, etc. It may be difficult to define the reason.